# Getting Nuget restore and MSbuild errors while trying to build the Image from Dockerfile (Windows dotnet application)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My code is looking for the reference projects mentioned in the .sln file. However, it is not able to find the correct path. How should I mention the correct path or WORKDIR in the Dockerfile?

My project folder structure looks like

[image: Folder Structure]

```
 C:\Projects\Treserva.Main\S3\Web\Private\Genomforande\Source
```

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY *.sln .

COPY Client/*.csproj ./Client/
COPY Client/*.config ./Client/
COPY S3.Web.Private.TreservaCustomSinkLibrary/*.csproj ./S3.Web.Private.TreservaCustomSinkLibrary/
COPY Tests/*.csproj ./Tests/
COPY Tests/*.config ./Tests/
RUN nuget restore  
 

COPY . .

RUN  msbuild /p:Configuration=Release -r:False
 
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Client/S3.Web.Private.Genomforande.Client.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "S3.Web.Private.Genomforande.Client.dll"]
```

Error:

```
Step 15/21 : RUN  msbuild /p:Configuration=Release -r:False
 ---> Running in 89a36fa56f4b
MSBuild version 17.7.2+d6990bcfa for .NET Framework
Build started 10/4/2023 8:31:34 AM.

Project "C:\src\s3.web.private.genomforande.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
ValidateProjects:
  The project "S3.Common.Components.RemoteServer" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
C:\src\s3.web.private.genomforande.sln.metaproj : error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Common\Core\Source\Core\S3.Web.Common.Core.csproj" was not found. [C:\src\s3.web.private.genomforande.sln]
C:\src\s3.web.private.genomforande.sln.metaproj : error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Modules\Genomforande\Source\Domain\S3.Modules.Genomforande.Domain.csproj" was not found. [C:\src\s3.web.private.genomforande.sln]
C:\src\s3.web.private.genomforande.sln.metaproj : error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Modules\Genomforande\Source\Facade\S3.Modules.Genomforande.Facade.csproj" was not foun
```